# How to get a vector from two points

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I am trying to find the bond angle between two vectors in a tetrahedron that is, the angle between BE and DE

[image: 1]

however seems like the vectors are wrong.

Those vectors we find subtracting points
$$E = (1/2,1/2,1/2) $$
$$B=(0,1,0)$$
$$D = (1,1,1)$$

$$BE = (1/2,-1/2,1/2)$$
$$ED = (1/2,1/2,1/2)$$

However, solving for $\theta$ in the dot product gives me the wrong angle

$$\cos\theta = \frac{BE  \cdot DE}{|BE||DE|}$$
$$\theta = 1,91.$$

Comment: Remember that you are working with radians. If you want degrees you must multiply by $\frac{180}{\pi}$.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thank you sir it gets the right answer

Comment: Note also that the second vector you have is actually $ED$, because $DE=(-1/2,-1/2,-1/2)$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis that's correct thank you

Comment: Also: Be careful. To get $\overrightarrow{AB}$, you take $\vec B - \vec A$, not the other way around.

Comment: The diagram is too small

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a simple typo or unit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing your work, we have that $\cos(\theta)=\frac{BE \cdot DE}{|BE||DE|}=\frac{\frac{-1}{4}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}=\frac{\frac{-1}{4}}{\frac{3}{4}}=\frac{-1}{3}.$

So, the angle $\theta$ between $BE$ and $DE$ is given by $\cos^{-1}\big(\frac{-1}{3}\big) \approx1.9106^c.$

Comment: you forgot the minus in the 1/3